# how to load but not trigger a viewmodal in durandal?

Tags: javascript, frontend, durandal, durandal-2.0

I would like to load a view manually without navigating to it. so in my code the following:

```
 router.navigate(url);
```

loads the view and also activates it and navigate to it. I wan all of these except I don't wanna navigate to it. So I want something like this:

```
 router.load(url);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can use the `compose` binding. Please see the [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html) for durandal composition.

Comment: I guess you can return false from the canActivate() hook, so that that view is not activated.